# How to use special character in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, icacls

How can I use the special character: á in Inno Setup?

For example:

Without special character at Parameters:

```
Filename: "{sys}\icacls.exe"; Parameters: """{app}\IRs\IRS.FDB"" /grant Todos:F /inheritance:d"; Flags: runhidden shellexec
```

But, when there is a special character the command doesn't work as below:

```
Filename: "{sys}\icacls.exe"; Parameters: """{app}\IRs\IRS.FDB"" /grant Usuários:F /inheritance:d"; Flags: runhidden shellexec
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error, it doesn't do what you expect it to do, ...?

Comment: I don't get an error. The script above is to set permission in one archive of Windows Explorer (Set full permission to "Usuários" group). But the script doesn't set the permission because there this char. Did you understand?

Comment: No, I didn't understand which is why I thought more precise information would be required. You have an encoding problem and the way it manifests itself can suggest solutions or workarounds.

Comment: I already solved my problem. Thanks. See the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I workaround the issue by using the group SID:

```
Filename: "{sys}\icacls.exe"; Parameters: """{app}\IRs\IRS.FDB"" /grant *S-1-5-32-545:(F) /inheritance:d"; Flags: runhidden shellexec
```

Comment: Yes. This seems to be a much better choice because what would be the benefit of granting access rights to a hardcoded personality like `Usuários` ? Me and many people don't have such group in the system.

Comment: Yes. The SID is universal and works fine to all languages (Usuários / Users ... etc.)